# Thread Fails to Exit On Application Exit - C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2008, messaging, exit

My application creates a thread that polls for Windows messages.  When it is time to close down, my application sends the `WM_QUIT` message.

In the application thread, this is how I am attempting to shut things down:

```
if ( _hNotifyWindowThread != NULL )
{
    ASSERT(_pobjNotifyWindow != NULL);

    ::SendMessage( _pobjNotifyWindow->m_hWnd, WM_QUIT, 0, 0 );
    ::WaitForSingleObject( _hNotifyWindowThread, 50000L );
    ::CloseHandle( _hNotifyWindowThread ); // <-- PC never gets here.
    _hNotifyWindowThread = NULL;
}
```

This is the message pump running in my thread function:

```
// Start the message pump...
while ( (bRetVal = ::GetMessage(
    &msg,                           // message structure
    _pobjNotifyWindow->m_hWnd,      // handle to window whose messages are to be retrieved
    WM_DEVICECHANGE,                // lowest message value to retrieve
    WM_DEVICECHANGE                 // highest message value to retrieve
    )) != 0 )
{
    switch ( bRetVal )
    {
    case -1:                        // Error generated in GetMessage.
        TRACE(_T("NotifyWindowThreadFn : Failed to get notify window message.\r\n\tError: %d\r\n\tFile: %s\r\n\tLine: %d\r\n"), ::GetLastError(), __WFILE__, __LINE__);
        return ::GetLastError();
        break;

    default:                        // Other message received.
        ::TranslateMessage( &msg );
        ::DispatchMessage( &msg );
        break;
    }
}

delete _pobjNotifyWindow;           // Delete the notify window.

return msg.wParam;                  // Return exit code.
```

The [Microsoft documentation for `GetMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644936%28VS.85%29.aspx) states:

> If the function retrieves the WM_QUIT message, the return value is zero.
>
> Note that GetMessage always retrieves WM_QUIT messages, no matter which values you specify for wMsgFilterMin and wMsgFilterMax.

If this is the case, then I would expect a call to `GetMessage` that retrieves the `WM_QUIT` message to return 0.  However, debugging leaves me to believe that the message is not received properly.  What is odd is that I can place a breakpoint in the `WndProc` function, and it seems to get the `WM_QUIT` message.

What am I doing wrong?  Should I be using a different function for posting messages between threads?  Thanks.

Comment: The use of message-filter is intended to give priority to certain important messages. You should alse respond to other messages in the messagequeue.

Comment: This doesn't work ::SendMessage( _pobjNotifyWindow->m_hWnd, WM_QUIT, 0, 0 );

Comment: To shut things down use : DestroyWindow( _pobjNotifyWindow->m_hWnd ) and in the windowprocedure : case WM_DESTROY : PostQuitMessage( 0 ); and replace GetMessage(...) in GetMessage( &msg ,NULL ,0 ,0 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This the complete answer (I'm almost sure):

replace

```
::SendMessage( _pobjNotifyWindow->m_hWnd, WM_QUIT, 0, 0 );
```

with

```
::PostMessage( _pobjNotifyWindow->m_hWnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0 );
```

replace

```
 ( (bRetVal = ::GetMessage( &msg, _pobjNotifyWindow->m_hWnd, WM_DEVICECHANGE, WM_DEVICECHANGE )) != 0 )
```

with `( (bRetVal = ::GetMessage( &msg, NULL ,0 ,0 )) != 0 )`

In your WindowsProcedure :

```
 case WM_CLOSE : DestroyWindow( hWnd ); break; //can be return 

 case WM_DESTROY : PostQuitMessage( 0 );
```

Comment: Thanks, Edwin.  I'm accepting your answer because it provides the most detail.  However, I did not need to change the `hWnd` parameter of `GetMessage` to get it working.  I did implement the other changes you recommended.

Comment: @Jim Fell: Glad to have helped you.

Comment: @Jim: just be careful on looping over `::GetMessage()` with `hWnd != NULL` because you're ignoring all other thread messages, including `WM_TIMER`. If this is a short-lived window, it might be OK, but keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1):

While my knowledge of the WinAPI has limits, it seems WM_QUIT is special and not meant to be posted like other messages.

According to [Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/11/04/489028.aspx):

> Like the WM_PAINT, WM_MOUSEMOVE, and WM_TIMER messages, the WM_QUIT message is not a "real" posted message. Rather, it is one of those messages that the system generates as if it were posted, even though it wasn't.

.

> When a thread calls PostQuitMessage, a flag in the queue state is set that says, "If somebody asks for a message and there are no posted messages, then manufacture a WM_QUIT message." This is just like the other "virtually posted" messages.

.

> PostThreadMessage just places the message in the thread queue (for real, not virtually), and therefore it does not get any of the special treatment that a real PostQuitMessage triggers.

So you should probably be using PostQuitMessage.

Of course, there may be ways to work around the current odd behavior (as per other answers). But given the description of WM_QUIT being special, you may want to use PostQuitMessage anyway.

Comment: I've used this as a stop condition before, and it works just fine. However, it's not intercepted unless `GetMessage()` uses `hWnd=NULL`. Furthermore, it has to be posted using `PostThreadMessage()`.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems with this code.

1. `::GetMessage()` doesn't stop because you're using the `hWnd` parameter with something else than `NULL`. You need to fetch the *thread* messages to get `::GetMessage()` to return `0`.
2. Following on the logic in (1), you need to post the message using `::PostThreadMessage()` to put it in the thread's message queue.

All of this is rather well illustrated by the fact the `::PostQuitMessage(status)` is a shorthand for

```
::PostThreadMessage(::GetCurrentThreadId(), WM_QUIT, status, 0);
```

**EDIT**:

It seems that people have been led into thinking that `::PostThreadMessage(...,WM_QUIT,...);` doesn't work because it doesn't get the special treatement of setting the `QS_QUIT` flag that is set by `::PostQuitMessage()`. If that was the case, then there would be no way to send `WM_QUIT` to another thread's message queue. Here is proof that it works anyways.

In particular, pay attention to the constants `Use_PostQuitMessage` and `GetMessage_UseWindowHandle`. Feel free to change the values and play around with the code. It works just as advertised in my answer, except that I mistakenly used `::GetCurrentThread()` rather than `::GetCurrentThreadId()` before trying it out.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

namespace {

        // Doesn't matter if this is 'true' or 'false'.
    const bool Use_PostQuitMessage        = false;

        // Setting this to 'true' prevents the application from closing.
    const bool GetMessage_UseWindowHandle = false;

    void post_quit_message ()
    {
        if ( Use_PostQuitMessage ) {
            ::PostQuitMessage(0);
        }
        else {
            ::PostThreadMessageW(::GetCurrentThreadId(), WM_QUIT, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    ::BOOL get_message ( ::HWND window, ::MSG& message )
    {
        if ( GetMessage_UseWindowHandle ) {
            return (::GetMessageW(&message, window, 0, 0));
        }
        else {
            return (::GetMessageW(&message, 0, 0, 0));
        }
    }

    ::ULONG __stdcall background ( void * )
    {
            // Allocate window in background thread that is to be interrupted.
        ::HWND window = ::CreateWindowW(L"STATIC", 0, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
            0, 0, 512, 256, 0, 0, ::GetModuleHandleW(0), 0);
        if ( window == 0 ) {
            std::cerr << "Could not create window." << std::endl;
            return (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

            // Process messages for this thread's windows.
        ::ShowWindow(window, SW_NORMAL);
        ::MSG message;
        ::BOOL result = FALSE;
        while ((result = get_message(window,message)) > 0)
        {
                // Handle 'CloseWindow()'.
            if ( message.message == WM_CLOSE )
            {
                post_quit_message(); continue;
            }
                // Handling for 'ALT+F4'.
            if ((message.message == WM_SYSCOMMAND) &&
                (message.wParam == SC_CLOSE))
            {
                post_quit_message(); continue;
            }
                // Dispatch message to window procedure.
            ::TranslateMessage(&message);
            ::DispatchMessageW(&message);
        }
            // Check for error in 'GetMessage()'.
        if ( result == -1 )
        {
            std::cout << "GetMessage() failed with error: "
                << ::GetLastError() << "." << std::endl;
            return (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

}

int main ( int, char ** )
{
        // Launch window & message pump in background thread.
    ::DWORD id = 0;
    ::HANDLE thread = ::CreateThread(0, 0, &::background, 0, 0, &id);
    if ( thread == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) {
        std::cerr << "Could not launch thread." << std::endl;
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

        // "do something"...
    ::Sleep(1000);

        // Decide to close application.
    ::PostThreadMessageW(id, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);

        // Wait for everything to shut down.
    ::WaitForSingleObject(thread, INFINITE);

        // Return background thread's success code.
    ::DWORD status = EXIT_FAILURE;
    ::GetExitCodeThread(thread,&status);
    return (status);
}
```

**P.S.**:

To actually test the single-threaded use of `::PostThreadMessage(::GetCurrentThreadId(),...);` invoke `::background(0);` in main instead of launching the thread.

Comment: PostQuitMessage doesn't actually post a message at all. It just sets a bit in the wake flags. OTOH, PostThreadMessage actually *does* append a posted message to a thread's posted message queue. See the book in my answer for details.

Comment: @Alex: that's speculation on the internal implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess. Your quit code is called from within a message loop call from another window which has its own message pump? According to MSDN for WaitForSingleObject you block the current UI thread indefinitely and prevent processing its own messages.

From
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687032%28VS.85%29.aspx

> Use caution when calling the wait
>   functions and code that directly or
>   indirectly creates windows. If a
>   thread creates any windows, it must
>   process messages. Message broadcasts
>   are sent to all windows in the system.
>   A thread that uses a wait function
>   with no time-out interval may cause
>   the system to become deadlocked. Two
>   examples of code that indirectly
>   creates windows are DDE and the
>   CoInitialize function. Therefore, if
>   you have a thread that creates
>   windows, use MsgWaitForMultipleObjects
>   or MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx, rather
>   than WaitForSingleObject.

It could be that the WM_Quit message is broadcast to your own window which does not process any messages due to your WaitForSingleObject call. Try instead MsgWaitForMultipleOjbects which tries to call your message loop from time to time.

Yours,
  Alois Kraus

Answer (score 0):

`WM_QUIT` is not a window message, so you shouldn't be sending it to a window. Try using [`PostThreadMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644946%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) instead:

```
PostThreadMessage(GetThreadId(_hNotifyWindowThread), WM_QUIT, 0, 0);
```

If that doesn't work, try posting a dummy message to your window:

```
::PostMessage( _pobjNotifyWindow->m_hWnd, WM_APP, 0, 0 );
```

and use it as a signal to quit in your window procedure:

```
case WM_APP:
  PostQuitMessage(0);
```

Comment: This is a partial answer. See Edwin's answer for details.

Comment: PostThreadMessage(GetThreadId(_hNotifyWindowThread), WM_QUIT, 0, 0) will not result in (0 == GetMessage(...))

Comment: @Edwin: oh yes it does. I added a *full* running example in my answer. Feel free to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your GetMessage(...) retrieves only message of the window you supplied. However WM_QUIT does not have a window associated with it. You Need to call  GetMessage without a window handle (i.e. NULL) which retrieve any message in the Message-Queue.

Comment: You typically use PostQuitMessage in response to WM_DESTROY message of your main\thread window. WM_DESTROY is generated by DestroyWindow( hWin );

Comment: This is a partial answer, see casablanca's answer for details.

Comment: @André Caron: It doesn't say so in the documentation of PostQuitMessage. You don't need PostThreadMessage.

Comment: you need it if you're going to post `WM_QUIT` in another thread's message queue, as per OP's request.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on what TheUndeadFish said; there's a "secret" undocumented `QS_QUIT` flag set in the wake flags of the thread's message queue when PostQuitMessage is called. GetMessage looks at its wake flags in a particular order to determine what message to process next.

If it finds that `QS_QUIT` is set, it generates a `WM_QUIT` message and causes `GetMessage` to return FALSE.

You can get a thread's *documented* wake flags that are currently set with [GetQueueStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644940%28VS.85%29.aspx).

The details can be found in [Programming Applications for Microsoft Windows](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1572319968), 4th Edition (unfortunately, the newest edition removed these topics).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think that in all the years the backing code has been in operation `::PostTheadMessage(...,WM_QUIT,...);` would forget to set a flag set by `::PostQuitMessage()`.

Comment: @Andre, those functions do two different things. The latter doesn't post any messages, it merely sets a flag.

Comment: I'm gessing there's a special case for `WM_QUIT` in `PostThreadMessage()` because it works just fine. I'll post sample code in my answer.

Comment: see my updated answer for proof/demonstration that both end up setting the same flag.